# Method return value as service parameter

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use a method-return-value as a DI-parameter.
The concrete use-case is that I have a service that has the logic of calculating a users-country-code like:

```
$user->getCountryCode();
```

On the other hand I have many services that depend on the country like:

```
$foo = new Foo('UK');
$bar = new Bar('USA');
```

I know that I can inject the User service into Foo / Bar, but that creates an odd dependency as these services don't need a user they just need the country-code.

Is there a way for me to write a service-description along the lines of:

```
  my_services.foo:
    class: Foo
    arguments:
      - @user.getCountryCode
```

Edit:
I'm using symfony 2.4 with yml configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Service factory method (compatible with all Symfony2 versions)

Service definitions:

```
# services.yml

FooFactory:
  class: Foo\FooBundle\Service\FooFactory
  arguments: [@user_country_code_calc_service]

FooService:
  class: Foo\FooBundle\Service\FooService
  factory_service: FooFactory
  factory_method: create
```

And your factory:

```
// FooFactory.php

class FooFactory
{
    private $countryCodeCalculator;

    public function __construct(UserCountryCodeCalculator $countryCodeCalculator)
    {
        $this->countryCodeCalculator = $countryCodeCalculator;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $countryCode = $this->countryCodeCalculator->calculate(...);

        return new FooService($countryCode);
    }
}
```

Now when you inject `@FooFactory` in any of your services, Symfony will actually call `FooFactory::create` and inject that method's result into it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Expression language method (compatible with Symfony versions >= 2.4)

```
# services.yml

foo_service:
  class: Foo\FooBundle\Service\FooService
  arguments: ["=service('user_countrycode_calc_service').calculateCountryCode()"]
```

Comment: This wont let me inject "scalar" values as a service requires a valid class.

Comment: remove `@` from argument beginning, I made a typo

Comment: Actually the `@` is needed (as show in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language)). I personnaly use it to include the MasterRequest Method only (`"GET"`/`"POST"`..) and it works : `"@=service('request_stack').getMasterRequest().getMethod()"`